# Cannot remove the file - "No such file or directory"

Tags: ntfs, rm

Yesterday I found this file in my git repo and I can't get rid of it no matter how hard I try.

The file is located on a **NTFS** disk.

```
sebastian@protean /media/sebastian/DATA/04 - PROJECTS/02 - MANAGER/00 - PRIVATE FILES/Git/web/.git/objects/20
$ ls -lb
3e3bf9d5355548b5e410f56154156f85ed96bd
sebastian@protean /media/sebastian/DATA/04 - PROJECTS/02 - MANAGER/00 - PRIVATE FILES/Git/web/.git/objects/20
$ sudo chmod 777 3e3bf9d5355548b5e410f56154156f85ed96bd
sebastian@protean /media/sebastian/DATA/04 - PROJECTS/02 - MANAGER/00 - PRIVATE FILES/Git/web/.git/objects/20
$ sudo rm -f 3e3bf9d5355548b5e410f56154156f85ed96bd
sebastian@protean /media/sebastian/DATA/04 - PROJECTS/02 - MANAGER/00 - PRIVATE FILES/Git/web/.git/objects/20
$ ll
total 36K
drwxrwx---  1   Sebastian   Sebastian 4,OK bre 23 21:41 ./
drwxrwx---  1   Sebastian   Sebastian  32K bre 23 21:34 ../
-rwxrwx---  2   Sebastian   Sebastian    0 bre 24 10:59 3e3bf9d5355548b5e410f56154156f85ed96bd*
sebastian@protean /media/sebastian/DATA/04 - PROJECTS/02 - MANAGER/00 - PRIVATE FILES/Git/web/.git/objects/20
$ rm 3e3bf9d5355548b5e410f56154156f85ed96bd
rm: cannot remove '3e3bf9d5355548b5e410f56154156f85ed96bd': No such file or directory
```

Any clues on how to delete this corrupted file?

Comment: Run `ntfsfix` on the partition after unmounting it. Or run chkdsk from Windows.

Comment: ntfsfix didn't helped (maybe I did something wrong?) but chkdsk from Windows did. Thank you, Muru. If you post it as and answer, I will confirm it.

Comment: The actual text from your output would be easier to process than trying to work with the picture.  Will you consider editing your question and putting the actual text rather than an image of the text?

Comment: Probably because `ntfsfix` doesn't really fix anything, except the dirty bit. :)

Comment: @L.D.James good point. I OCRed OP's picture.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Impressive OCR program.  Which one is it?

Comment: @L.D.James one of the many low cost Mac apps based on the Abbyy FineReader SDK (specifically Cisdem PDF Converter OCR). I carefully processed the pic with GIMP first, though.

Comment: PS: but honestly, OCR on monospace fonts is usually easier than most other tasks. Still, I had to tweak only a few chars and spaces after the process so yeah, the output was very good.